Properties of a function to determine the n-th digit of a number
I currently work with the function
$$
B_i(n) = \left\lfloor\frac n{2^{i-1}} \right\rfloor \mod 2
$$
which returns the $i$-th digit in the binary representation of the natural number $n$. E.g. $B_3(13_{10}) = B_3(1101_2) = \lfloor 11.01_2 \rfloor \mod 2  = 11_2 \mod 2 = 1 $
I want to proove, that $B_{i+1}(2n + 1) = B_i(n)$, which seems intuitive to me: I multiply by two, so the last digit is 0 and I shift everything to the left and therefore read the bit one way further to the left. Adding one doesn't change the $i$-th bit, because the least significant bit is 0. But I fail to prove that using the definition of that function.

@CalvinLin I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean. Can you try to explain it in other words?

I suspect that the comment of@CalvinLin was referring to your originally posted definition of $~B_i(n),~$ which had a typo in it.  The typo has been corrected so that the denominator has been changed from $~2^{n-1}~$ to $~2^{i-1}.$

Let us prove more precisely that
$$\left\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{2^i} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac n{2^{i-1}} \right\rfloor.$$
Let $$a:=\left\lfloor\frac n{2^{i-1}} \right\rfloor.$$
By definition, $2^{i-1}a\le n<2^{i-1}(a+1)$, i.e. $2^{i-1}a\le n\le2^{i-1}(a+1)-1$. Equivalently,
$$2^ia+1\le2n+1\le2^i(a+1)-1,$$
which implies
$$a\le\frac{2n+1}{2^i}<a+1,$$
Q.E.D.

Thank you so, so much, really elegant way to show that! You helped me out once again, thanks a lot for your help Anne!
